# JDI watchpoints on Local Variables

Tags: java, debugging, jdi, jpda

I need to set watchpoints on Local Variables, but the problem is JDI allows `ModificationWatchpoint` and `AccessWatchpoint` to be set only on class/instance variables. Only approach I could think of is monitor stackframes after execution of each line, and keep current value of variables in `HashTable`. So I am declaring variable modification when value changes after execution of one line and I declare variables access when value of some other variable is modified and it contains value that some other variable also contains. But there is one  problem in my approach of finding variables access is suppose

```
x=10
z=x+30
```

In above case my approach will not find variable access of variable x.

So my question is is there any functionality supported by JDI to do above tasks ?

Comment: hey, how did you solve your problem?

Comment: It was not possible to find any solution with JDI. I used JavaParser library to solve above problem.